# Plot a 2D Region to Show Which Function is Bigger

Tags: plotting

Let us assume that we have two real functions $f(x_1,x_2)$ and $g(x_1,x_2)$.

I want to plot a 2D region of $\{(x_1, x_2)| f(x_1, x_2) \geq g(x_1, x_2)\}$.

The `Region` function seems cannot work well if f and g are complicated.
Is there any suggested function in Mathematica to do this job?

Answer (score 6):

It is quite difficult to understand what problems you faced, since you have not provided explicit code, so I am giving a very simple command just to get you started.

Assume the following functions

```
f[x1_][x2_] := x1^2 + 2*x2
g[x1_][x2_] := x1 + 2/x2
```

and then we can use

```
RegionPlot[f[x1][x2] >= g[x1][x2], {x1, 0, 4}, {x2, 0, 11}]
```

which returns a nice plot.

Another workaround that comes to mind is to use the `Plot3D` command. As an example

```
Plot3D[{f[x1][x2], g[x1][x2]}, {x1, -5, 5}, {x2, -10, 10}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But when f and g are rather complicated and computationally demanding, RegionPlot sometimes will generate unsatisfactory results. For example, some area which should be colored might become blank.

Answer (score 6):

```
f = x1 + x2*Sin[x1];
g = x1*x2 + Cos[x2]*x1;
ContourPlot[f - g, {x1, -10, 10}, {x2, -10, 10}, Contours -> {0}, 
 ContourShading -> {None, Red}, PlotPoints -> 80]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Note that you get better resolution also using `MaxRecursion` rather than just using `PlotPoints`, e.g.,  `PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 8`

Comment: That's a nice, nifty trick

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks! `MaxRecursion` work.